# c# - TableAdapter - Delete

Tags: c#, tabela-banco-de-dados, delete

Boa tarde, sou novo nessa área. Tenho de criar os botões Incluir, Alterar e Excluir de um sistema de vendas. Estou usando o tableAdapter e já consegui fazer o botão Incluir dá seguinte forma:

```
    private void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btnInserir.Enabled = false;
        btnAlterar.Enabled = false;
        btnExcluir.Enabled = false;
        btnGravar.Enabled = true;
        btnCancelar.Enabled = true;
        txtNome.Enabled = true;
        txtCPF.Enabled = true;
        txtEndereco.Enabled = true;
        txtTelefone.Enabled = true;

        pessoasTableAdapter taPessoa = new pessoasTableAdapter();
        string novoID;
        int valorCodigo;
        novoID = taPessoa.UltimoID().ToString();

        if (int.TryParse(novoID.ToString(), out valorCodigo)) {
            txtCodigo.Text = (valorCodigo + 1).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Código com valor inválido. Tente novamente.");
        }
    }
```

Sendo que é necessário a confirmação com o botão Gravar, que fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pessoasTableAdapter taPessoa = new pessoasTableAdapter();

        taPessoa.Insert(txtCodigo.Text, txtNome.Text, txtTelefone.Text, txtEndereco.Text, txtCPF.Text, txtFiado.Text);
        Limpar_Caixas();            
        string novoID;
        int valorCodigo;
        novoID = taPessoa.UltimoID().ToString();

        if (int.TryParse(novoID.ToString(), out valorCodigo))
        {
            txtCodigo.Text = (valorCodigo + 1).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Código com valor inválido. Tente novamente.");
        }
    }

    private void Limpar_Caixas()
    {
        foreach(Control ctr in this.Controls)
        {
            if(ctr is TextBox)
            {
                (ctr as TextBox).Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Agora estou tendo problemas com o botão excluir:

```
    private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pessoasTableAdapter taPessoa = new pessoasTableAdapter();

        DataTable dtPessoa;
        dtPessoa = taPessoa.PesquisaPessoa(txtCodigo.Text);

        if (dtPessoa.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pessoa não cadastrada.");
        }
        else
        {
            txtCodigo.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["idPessoa"].ToString();
            txtNome.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["nomePessoa"].ToString();
            txtEndereco.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["enderecoPessoa"].ToString();
            txtCPF.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["cpfPessoa"].ToString();
            txtTelefone.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["telefonePessoa"].ToString();
            txtFiado.Text = dtPessoa.Rows[0]["fiado"].ToString();           
        }

        if (MessageBox.Show("Confirma exclusão?", "Excluindo...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            taPessoa.Delete(txtCodigo.Text, txtNome.Text, txtEndereco.Text, txtTelefone.Text, txtCPF.Text, txtFiado.Text);
        }
    }
```

Ao inserir o código da pessoa, aparece todas as informações e uma janela para confirmar a exclusão. Ao clicar em sim, nada acontece. O que fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
taPessoa[0].Delete(txtCodigo.Text, txtNome.Text, txtEndereco.Text, txtTelefone.Text, txtCPF.Text, txtFiado.Text);
```

Comment: "Não é possível aplicar a indexação com [] a uma expressão do tipo "pessoasTableAdapter"."